# I think is an linking error in Geany with nanopi M1

Tags: gpio, geany, nanopi

how are you?. I have a big problem (or at least I don't know how to solve it) with Geany, using Debian jessie in a nanopi M1.

The history is like follows:

I'm trying to run some modified demo code that came with the nanopi M1 to control the GPIO ports, so, when I was tring to "Build" the program after compiled, it shows the following errors:

In the function main it says:

```
/tmp/ccwWOISx.o in function 'main'
......                  undefined reference to 'boardinit'
......                  undefined reference to 'pintoGPIO'
......                  undefined reference to 'openHW'
......                  undefined reference to 'selectHW'
......                  undefined reference to 'readHW'
......                  undefined reference to 'closeHW'
......
......
and about two or tree more errors of the same type "undefined reference" all 
related a functions of the hardware
```

I'm using gcc, the commands came precharged in geany and are:

Compile:

```
gcc -Wall -c "%f"
```

Build:

```
gcc -Wall -o "%f" "%e"
```

so I think (if I've understood what I readed in other posts in stackoverflow) that is a linking error but don't know how to solve it.

after that, I've modified the Build command to this:

```
gcc -Wall -c -o "%f" "%e"
```

this made to not to have errors but the file generated is now of the type "object code" (this is wrong) because I need "executable" files (without extension) and terminal give the following message:

```
bash: ./Matrix-ir_receiver: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I don't have any idea of how to solve this, please help!

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it was a linker problem, I needed to use the -lfahw and -lm options to build the executable. The first options one is specific for the ARM device, I think; after that the program runs flawlessly.